# Finding rows in MySQL Table that do NOT have certain text

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Suppose I want to find an article in a database table that includes the text "There were many bison" With phpMyAdmin, I can navigate to Search, choose a field, then choose Like %...%, and it will select the article that includes those words.

I'd like to know if there's a way to find all rows that do NOT include that string.

Let me explain my bigger goal. I'm working on articles about many animal species that are divided into sections on Classification, Distribution, Ecology, etc. Each section can be thought of as an independent article, and I was tempted to make unique tables for each of these sections. However, that would be a logistical nightmare; I'd need literally hundreds of tables.

So I just write one long article with each section beginning with something like this:

So if I have articles about 600 species in my database table, and I want to know which articles DO NOT include an Ecology section, I can simply search for all the rows that do not have that particular div, or something similar (e.g [h2]Ecology[/h2] - though with real tags, not brackets).

Is there a way to do that with phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench (which I downloaded and installed just today) or some other tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a NOT REGEX http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html with SQL.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that link. I saw the NOT REGEXP choice but didn't understand what it meant. I'm glad to see so many examples on that page...however, I haven't yet figured out how to do the simplest un-search of all. Can someone tell me what code I would type in if I wanted to find everything in a field that DOES NOT include this string?: <div class="divTopics" id="Ecology">

Comment: DUH...I found the answer; I thought I tried it and it didn't work, but I tried it again. I guess it was too simple to be believable. ;)

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to create a categories table on your database and then assign each article a category. That way you could create a query to select all the articles that have the specific category that you want.

```
example would be :
 table articles:
        -article_id (primary Key)
        -article
        -category_cat_id (foreign Key that references cat_id)

 table category
         - cat_id (primary Key)
         -cat_name

a query to select all the articles with the categry of lets say ecology: 
SELECT * FROM articles
LEFT JOIN category
ON articles.category_cat_id = category.cat_id
WHERE cat_name != 'ecology'(if you want to select all the articles except those with a ecology cateogry)

another alternative is 
WHERE cat_name = 'ecology'( if you want to select all posts with the category of ecology)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that. The main problem is the sheer number of projects I'm working on; I wondered if keeping such a table might become too big a chore. It's still an option, but I realized life would be much easier if I could determine which articles still need to be researched with a simple search operation.